# Is there a SOP Cast player available?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

Is there a good Sopcast player for Ubuntu?

Comment: It's a program that streams videos from the net using p2p. I never used it, but my brother was quite a fan. He uses it to watch in his laptop (under Windows) football (real football aka soccer) matches that were pay-only in Spanish TVs. The software enables him to see Asian or Arab TV channels that are not accessible normally (ip restrictions likely).

Comment: @Javier sweet! can you edit your question and add the information there so it's not buried in the comments in the future? thanks!

Comment: Yes sure I can edit, but it's not my question. I don't know if so much editing is polite here.

Answer (score 7):

I've used the Linux Sopcast Player by following the instructions outlined [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/install-linux-sopcast-player-040-in.html). It should be OK for you too, depending on your definition of "good". :)